# Gif is Slow in Visual Studio C# Winform Application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, animated-gif

I have try to display a gif in my windows forms application using pictureBox, Its works but gif is plays slower than the original gif.

I've tried to increase the speed of gif but after increasing also gif plays the same speed in Windows Forms pictureBox.
Help me to slove this issue.

Comment: Please show some code. How do you set up the picturebox?

Comment: I'm directly select gif in the pictureBox's properties.

Comment: The [ImageAnimator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imageanimator) class animates images at ~50ms per frame. If you need a different frame rate, you have to create the animation yourself

Comment: how to implement that custom animation